# Insert to list with variable names in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have three lists, named list0, list1 and list2.
Here is what i want to do

```
for n in range(10):
    x = n%3
    listx.append(n)
```

where x can be 0, 1 or 2. How can I do this? Basically, I don't want to create 3 if/elif cases but just change the third line in above program

PS - I know this not the best method for this problem but my project is quite different from this

Comment: Why don't you make it a list of lists or a dictionary of lists? Then you can do `list[x].append(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a list of lists?

```
lists = [[],[],[]]
for n in range(10):
    list[n%3].append(n)

list1,list2,list3 = lists
```

or just use `lists[i]`, which would scale better to bigger primes.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist, you can use `locals()` (or `globals()` to get your lists from the outer scope) to get your lists by name:

```
list0, list1, list2 = [], [], []

for n in range(10):
    x = n % 3
    locals()["list" + str(x)].append(n)

print(list0, list1, list2)  # [0, 3, 6, 9] [1, 4, 7] [2, 5, 8]
```

But that's really a bad practice.

Comment: Even worse practice if we're going there: `eval("list"+str(x)+".append("+str(n)+")")`